# Bootstrap boxes not fitting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my Boxes onces i resize my webpage (browser) i am not sure how to use it, i use "col-sm-3"

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="w-section inverse">
         <h3 class="section-title">User's Outfits</h3> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <div id="boxpic">
                        <img src="http://apinchofglitzandglam.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/dsc_0653.jpg?w=560&h=822" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="title" style="text-align:center;">Winter's Mist</div>
                    <p style="font-family:comic sans MS;width:250px;height:30px;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <div id="boxpic">
                        <img src="http://apinchofglitzandglam.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/dsc_0653.jpg?w=560&h=822" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="title" style="text-align:center;">Winter's Mist</div>
                    <p style="font-family:comic sans MS;width:250px;height:30px;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <div id="boxpic">
                        <img src="http://apinchofglitzandglam.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/dsc_0653.jpg?w=560&h=822" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="title" style="text-align:center;">Winter's Mist</div>
                    <p style="font-family:comic sans MS;width:250px;height:30px;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the images -> http://justpaste.it/STacKovErFloW

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your image is not resizing.
use this in your css style

```
.boxpic img {
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following class to your images:

```
img-responsive
```

An example is below:

### **[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvryhk7o/1/)**

Also, BootStrap works from a bottom-up sense... meaning, if you declare the columns to be medium, then both medium and large columns will stay consistent with what you declared, i.e:

```
col-md-3 therefore implies col-lg-3
```

Whereas if you declare an extra small column size then that stays consistent with every column possible, i.e:

```
col-xs-3 therefore implies col-sm-3, col-md-3, and col-lg-3
```

So if you want something on your webpage to stay consistent for all devices, then you can declare the smallest column size (xs) and have that take care of all small, medium, and large screen sizes. An example of this is below:

### **[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvryhk7o/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there is this issue now... i copied code from the second DEMO http://justpaste.it/STacKovErFloW

Comment: Can you provide me with more code? What is encompassing this content?